# WPF How to create a perfectly sectioned grid (thirds) that maintains size regardless of children sizes

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a basic grid that is split into thirds. Here is the XAML

```
<Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
</Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
```

Here is what the UI is suppose to look like
[image]

However, when too much text is added to the first textbox, the grid column automatically resizes. Which looks like this:[image]

My Question is: Why does the grid column automatically resize based on the textbox's size? Is there a way to create a perfectly sectioned grid that does not response to children's width?

I know in this case I could fix it using MaxWidth for either the column or textbox. However, this does not work for me since grids parent can be any width. So there is not way for me to set a constant MaxWidth.

EDIT: For those asking for clarity. The code I pasted in my first edit is enough to reproduce the issue. No more clarity is needed.

EDIT: This only appears to happen when the grid is placed in a ListBox. When the grid is not in a listbox, the grid columns maintain their width regardless of children content. Here is a video showing the difference between with/without listbox https://imgur.com/gO0e2w6

Below is my ListBox:

```
<ListBox ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" x:Name="VariablesTable"  SelectionMode="Extended" Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{x:Static vm:VariablesViewModel.Variables}" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch">
    <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"></Setter>
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0 0 0 0" />
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource BorderBrush}" />
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0, 0, 0, 0"/>
            <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0, 0, 0, 0"/>
            <Setter Property="Height" Value="45"/>
            <EventSetter Event="MouseMove" Handler="MouseMoveVariableEntry"/>
            <EventSetter Event="DragEnter" Handler="DragEnterVariableEntry"/>
            <EventSetter Event="DragOver" Handler="DragOverVariableEntry"/>
            <EventSetter Event="PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown" Handler="PreviewMouseLeftButtonDownVariableEntry"/>
            <EventSetter Event="PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp" Handler="PreviewMouseLeftButtonDownVariableEntry"/>

        </Style>
    </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate >
        <DataTemplate>
            <Border Background="#FF4A4A5E" BorderThickness="1" CornerRadius="8" Padding="10 5 10 5" Margin="0">
                <Grid >
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                    <TextBox Grid.Column="0"></TextBox>
                    <TextBox Grid.Column="1"></TextBox>
                    <TextBox Grid.Column="2"></TextBox>

                </Grid>
            </Border>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Comment: Because by declaring `*` the content will first try to justify the layout as there's no boundary provided to restrict the child element widths.  Might look into `SharedSizeGroup` or some of the other answers on the site.

Comment: @ChrisW. SharedSizeGroup does not appear to be a solution to this. And I am not aware of other solutions on this site.

But it seems odd that there is no way to evenly split a grid and maintain it regardless of children.

Comment: @Clemens It appears to only happen when the grid is in a ListBox. See the edit I added to my post. There is a video as well to show the difference.

Answer (score 1):

This is due to the fact that all Items are placed in the VirtualizingStackPanel. But this panel provides endless space for child elements.
If you limit the size of the ListBoxItem, then this limitation will be passed on to the Border and Grid children.
This can be done, for example, by binding the ListBoxItem size in the style.

```xml
        <ListBox ---------->
            <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                    <Setter Property="Width"
                            Value="{Binding ActualWidth, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=VirtualizingStackPanel}}"/>
```

Comment: This fixes it for me. Thanks!